# 3 divs in a row with backgrounds

Tags: html, css-float

I am trying to put 3 divs in a row [1][2][3].

[1] should have a background image repeating to the left

[2] must be centered. its 1000 px

[3] should have a background image repeating to the right

The problem is that [1] appears on the top of[2],[3] below [2] and the background images for [1] and [3]  don't appear. If I just put a color instead of the image,it appears(the path is correct).

HTML:

```
 <div id="topleft">left</div> 
 <div id="top" >  
      <div class="container"/>  
          <div id="header">Menu</div>  
      </div> 
 </div> 
 <div id="topright">right</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topleft {
  background-image: url(images/leftrepeat.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  float: left;
}

#top .container {  
  background-image:url(images/center.png);  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;  
  min-height:151px;  
  width:1000px;
  float: center;
}  

#topright {
  background-image: url(images/rightrepeat.png);
  float: right;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: I managed to put the divs on the same line by getting the topright over the topcontainer.Also by specifing a height,I can get the background images to appear but they won't repeat without a width mentioned.The problem is that I need them to repeat as much as needed by the screen resolution so I can't mention a width. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something inside the divs in order to have a background image to appear. You can´t have empty divs with just background image...
Like above said, try setting the width and height on the divs and you could put some text inside maybe with the same color as the background image. Or you could put a transparent image with the right width/height inside the div and then the background image behind...

And yeah, float left on all!

Try setting the width on the divs in percentage instead. This way they should automatically adjust after the screen size/resolution.

Comment: @miraco How about if you put the width in percentage? Then it should adjust after the screen..

Comment: considering that the center div has 1000px, what percentage should the left and right div have? Also, a problem could be the left divs background image going under the center div image(which is partially transparent so you can see the other image under).

Answer (score 0):

Changing all the floats to

```
  float:left;
```

will stack the three elements horizontally beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your 'topright' above the 'container' in the HTML

```
<div id="topleft"> 
  left
</div> 

<div id="topright">  
     right
</div> 

 <div id="top" >  
      <div class="container"/>  
          <div id="header">  
           Menu
           </div>  
       </div> 
</div>
```

Then the CSS for your container should remove the float: center; and add margin: 0 auto;

As for the images, just be sure of the paths as they should be appearing, and that the divs are large enough to display a background image.

Answer (score 0):

`float:center;` isn't valid - to put elements on the same line you can float them all left. For the rightmost element (#topright) you can optionally float it right, depending on your layout.

If you want #top to be on the same line as #topleft and #topright, it needs to be a floated element, rather than .container.

For your background images - have you tried setting a width and height for #topleft and #topright?